# Sympy partial derivations in a for-loop with items from a list

Tags: python, sympy

I want to run a number of partial derivations on a function created with sympy.
The function has several variables so I want to iterate over a list and pass the items to the diff() function. It seems that the function is bound to the symbols defined at the beginning of the code and the conversion of the list items into symbols makes no difference.

```
from sympy import Symbol, symbols, diff

x, y, z = symbols('x y z', real=True)

variables = ["x", "y", "z"]
function = x * y + z

for i in variables:
    v = Symbol(i)
    print(type(v))
    function_partial = diff(function, v)
    print(function_partial)
```

Output:

<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>

0

<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>

0

<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>

0

Comment: You seem to be getting different symbols back from `Symbol(i)` because the assumptions are different. Try using `Symbol(i, real=True)`.

Comment: Note that after running your code in an interactive shell, `x is Symbol("x", real=True)`  is `True`, while `x is Symbol("x")` is `False`

Comment: In general, it would probably be easier to work with the symbols directly instead of going between strings and symbols. For example, you could use `variables = [x, y, z]` and then iterate `for v in variables` directly.

Comment: Hi Brian. The acutal code is a bit more complex and the program reads the variables from a csv-file. With ``variables.append(Symbol(row[0], real=True))`` it works out just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are making extra steps and variables. The following simplification works fine:

```
from sympy import Symbol, symbols, diff
x, y, z = symbols('x y z', real=True)

variables = [x, y, z]
function = x * y + z

for i in variables:
    function_partial = diff(function, i)
    print(function_partial)
```